# Why can't I re-install YouTube? Error message: "Duplicate provider authority"

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, youtube

I'm in a bit of a problem. You see I have a preinstalled youtube app on my phone. Normally, there's an update and so I wanted to make the preinstalled one up-to-date without keeping the older version so I uninstalled it using Link2SD. Now when I was about to reinstall youtube with the latest version, I keep getting an error. So now my phone is stuck without a YouTube app. I even tried sideloading but it still fails to install.

The error I'm having is

[image]

Comment: Don't make people go somewhere else to get the information they need to answer your question.

Comment: I don't see why you uninstalled the app in order to update it. Try the reinstall the app provided by the manufacturer.

Comment: @AlEverett That is just a screenshot of my screen. I posted this using my phone last night so it's kinda hard to embed and get the image link from dropbox.

Comment: @slybloty I uninstalled it so that a new fresh installation should get it installed to my SD card.

Comment: I recommend using Titanium Backup's "Integrate updates of system apps into ROM" feature instead, it's nice and simple.

Comment: Screenshots are actually pretty easy to embed. See my edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your device rooted? If so you may use adb or any root supported file manager to manually remove it and re-install it from Play store.

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same issue except for the reason that YouTube got messed up.

I recovered using Root Explorer (installed from Google Play) on my rooted phone.

I used the search function to look for youtube (search is case insensitive) and it came back with five files.  I used multi-select and deleted them all.  I rebooted the phone just in case and then I was able to install YouTube with no more errors.